# Terminal becomes transparent after sleep. 5.0 Juno

Tags: display, pantheon-terminal, suspend

So I recently installed elementary Os and I've been experiencing this problem:
After I log back in from sleep state, the terminal its all transparent, except the header bar.
Moving the mouse over the lines makes them visible again, but as soon as another window is over the terminal, or its minimized the same problem occurs.
Opening a new terminal doesn't fix it since it behaves in the same manner. Only a restart seems to fix this.
I'm using intel integrated graphics, if its any help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

So I've been looking and it seems that this is related to the Intel integrated graphics device. It's not only affecting terminal but text shown on some other GTK applications.

On the Arch wiki I found the following:

> Font and screen corruption in GTK+ applications (missing glyphs after suspend/resume)
>   Should you experience missing font glyphs in GTK+ applications, the following workaround might help. Edit /etc/environment to add the following line:

Edit '/etc/environment' and add the following line:

> COGL_ATLAS_DEFAULT_BLIT_MODE=framebuffer

It seems to be working.